Patching UDP checksum when changing some bytes
I'm trying to figure out how to patch the UDP checksum if I change some values in the payload.
Assume that I have some 16-bit big-endian values [x_1, ..., x_n] in a UDP packet and I change them to [y_1, ..., y_n]. Assume these are at distinct offsets and aligned to a 16-bit boundary. What's the impact on the UDP header checksum?
So I understand that if I flip the bits of the original checksum, then subtract the x_i and add the y_i and flip the bits again, then I probably get fairly close to what I should have. My problem is understanding the effect of the
while (sum >> 16) {
    sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
}

loop that's used to cram any bits of the upper 16-bits of the sum to the lower 16-bits. As this operation was applied to the original checksum, so it's not as straightforward as just a sum of the original 16-bit words.
EDIT: The following RFC has the answer: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1624
